# Jmeter Image uploading script

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner

I need to do load test on a web application where images will be uploaded(Similar to the site https://imgbb.com/). I am unable to perform this. Can anyone help me out with this.

I have tried working it out but no luck. Please find the below screenshots for reference. Firstly after recording the script i have enhanced the script with correlation and have executed, then I have received the following error.
[image]

After doing some R&D, I have made certain changes(Implementation from default to HttpClient4, and Request parameters to Body Data) and executed again, still no luck.
**Changes Made**
[image]

**Result**
[image]

Can someone please suggest now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing something very weird. The easiest way to create a file upload request using JMeter is just **recording** it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

1. Start JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder
2. Import `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` file into your browser (it is required as `imgbb.com` is using [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) protocol and JMeter will need [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) certificate in order to be able to decrypt and record secure traffic)
3. Copy the file you'll be uploading into "bin" folder of your JMeter installation (otherwise JMeter will not be able to find it)
4. Perform upload request in the browser - JMeter will capture it under [Recording Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)

See [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) article for more details.

---

Just in case if you want or need to build the request manually the relevant [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler configuration should look like:

1. `Parameters` tab:

   [image: JMeter HTTP Request Parameters]
2. `Files Upload` tab

   [image: JMeter Files Upload Tab]
3. You should see the following output in the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener:

   [image: JMeter File Upload View Results Tree listener]

Comment: Dmitri T, thanks for the solution. But im still wondering why the same has not worked when i have recorded through Blazemeter.

Answer (score 0):

To upload files from JMeter Http sampler you have to add file path to http sample and corresponding mime type..

Open Files to upload tab in the HTTP sampler  enter the file path ..
If the file is in JMeter's bin directory you can give relative path , if the file resides somewhere on the disk give absolute path and enter corresponding mime type 
You can find mime type [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/mime-types-complete-list/).
For more information on load testing with JMeter please follow the [link](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/03/apache-jmeter-load-testing-easily-run-load-tests-scale-cloud/)

Comment: Thanks for your response Rohit. I have followed the similar approach initially and the result is the first screen attached in my description.